# Create user account for current logged in user

Tags: windows-7, batch, automation, user

We have over 100 users that need to be made users on their Windows 7 machines. It's very easy to write a script using net user, but it doesn't get us a level of automation we need. I would like to be able to detect the current logged in user and fill that into the net user.

It can be an auto-detect of the %username% or we could have each user enter information in a dialog input box. I have found examples of these, but I am not an expert in batch so creating the link between the input data to net user is unclear to me. Is there someone who can fill in these gaps?

Comment: Why are you not using Active Directory for that?

Comment: We are. The problem is that a user account is created for each user that logs into a computer. This gets the user the necessary folders, but not a full profile. We need to create a user profile (some with administrative rights) on machines that some users log into on a regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a script for automatically logging you can see here:
[Creating logon scripts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758918%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) Most likely this is what you need.

If you need to change the default login dialog, it is either a third-party solutions, or write your library, you can see here: [Customizing GINA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163803.aspx)

Write in the form of steps or theses goals automation. And the scenarios step by step, to the desired results in each item.

If you take into account the clarification, you can help the group policies and OU:

[Deploy Roaming User Profiles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649079.aspx)

[Designing an OU Structure that Supports Group Policy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783140%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)